# Array binary tree

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, root

I need to implement a function in three definitions, and ive created initially an empty binary tree constructor with the fixed length of 512 to hold the elements of the three.

This is my empty binary tree constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._maxArraySize = 512
    self._array = [None]*self._maxArraySize
    self._size = 0
```

Fot the hard part i need to implement a function that places the element e at the root of an empty tree and returns the position of the root in _add_root

In the _add_left function it should place the element e in the left child of p and returns the position of the child

And lastly the _add_right function should place the element e in the right child of p and return the position of the child.

The code that ive done but dont work is showed below, everything is given except the nonpublic mutators.

```
from binary_tree import BinaryTree

class ArrayBinaryTree(BinaryTree):
  """List representation of a binary tree structure."""

  #-------------------------- nested Position class --------------------------
  class Position(BinaryTree.Position):
    """An abstraction representing the location of a single element."""

    def __init__(self, container, arrayIndex):
      """Constructor should not be invoked by user."""
      self._container = container
      self._arrayIndex = arrayIndex

    def element(self):
      """Return the element stored at this Position."""
      if self._arrayIndex > self._container._maxArraySize:
          raise ValueError('invalid position')
      return self._container._array[self._arrayIndex]

    def __eq__(self, other):
      """Return True if other is a Position representing the same location."""
      return type(other) is type(self) and other._container is self._container and \
    other._arrayIndex == self._arrayIndex

  #------------------------------- utility methods -------------------------------
  def _validate(self, p):
    """Return associated array index, if position is valid."""
    if not isinstance(p, self.Position):
      raise TypeError('p must be proper Position type')
    if p._container is not self:
      raise ValueError('p does not belong to this container')
    return p._arrayIndex

  def _make_position(self, arrayIndex):
    """Return Position instance for given array index."""
    if  arrayIndex >= self._maxArraySize:
      return None
    if self._array[arrayIndex] is None:
      return None
    return self.Position(self, arrayIndex)

  def __init__(self):
    """Create an initially empty binary tree."""
    self._maxArraySize = 512
    self._array = [None]*self._maxArraySize
    self._size = 0


  #-------------------------- public accessors --------------------------
  def __len__(self):
    """Return the total number of elements in the tree."""
    # TODO: Implement the len() operator that returns the total number of elements
    # in the tree.
    return self._size
  
  def root(self):
    """Return the root Position of the tree (or None if tree is empty)."""
    # TODO: Implement the root function from the Tree base class.
    # Return the root Position of the tree. Use _make_position to create
    # the Position instance.
    return self._make_position(self._array)

  def parent(self, p):
    """Return the Position of p's parent (or None if p is root)."""
    # TODO: Implement the parent function from the Tree base class.
    # Return the Position of p's parent. Use _validate to get the 
    # index of p and _make_position to create the parent Position instance.
    arrayIndex = self._validate(p)
    return self._make_position(arrayIndex._parent)
  
  def left(self, p):
    """Return the Position of p's left child (or None if no left child)."""
    # TODO: Implement the left function from the BinaryTree base class.
    # Return the Position of p's left child. Use _validate to get the 
    # index of p and _make_position to create the left child Position instance.
    arrayIndex = self._validate(p)
    return self._make_position(arrayIndex._left)

  def right(self, p):
    """Return the Position of p's right child (or None if no right child)."""
    # TODO: Implement the right function from the BinaryTree base class.
    # Return the Position of p's right child. Use _validate to get the 
    # index of p and _make_position to create the right child Position instance.
    arrayIndex = self._validate(p)
    return self._make_position(arrayIndex._right)

  def num_children(self, p):
    """Return the number of children of Position p."""
    # TODO: Implement the num_children function from the Tree base class.
    # Return the number of children of p. Use _validate to get the index or
    # use left and right.
    arrayIndex = self._validate(p)
    count = 0
    if arrayIndex._left is not None:
      count += 1
    if arrayIndex._right is not None:
      count += 1
    return count

  #-------------------------- nonpublic mutators --------------------------
  def _add_root(self, e):
    """Place element e at the root of an empty tree and return new Position.

    Raise ValueError if tree nonempty.
    """
    # TODO: Implement a function that places the element e at the root 
    # of an empty tree and returns the Position of the root. Use 
    # _make_position to create the Position instance.
    if self._array is not None:
      raise ValueError('Root exists')
    self._size = 1
    self._array = self._array(e)
    return self._make_position(self._array)

  def _add_left(self, p, e):
    """Create a new left child for Position p, storing element e.

    Return the Position of new element.
    Raise ValueError if Position p is invalid or p already has a left child.
    """
    # TODO: implement a function that places the element e in the left child of
    # p and returns the Position of the child. Use _validate to get the 
    # index of p and _make_position to create the left child Position instance.
    arrayIndex = self._validate(p)
    if arrayIndex._left is not None:
      raise ValueError('Left child exists')
    self._size += 1
    arrayIndex._left = self._array(e, 2*p + 1)
    return self._make_position(arrayIndex._left)

  def _add_right(self, p, e):
    """Create a new right child for Position p, storing element e.

    Return the Position of new element.
    Raise ValueError if Position p is invalid or p already has a right child.
    """
    # TODO: implement a function that places the element e in the right child of
    # p and returns the Position of the child. Use _validate to get the 
    # index of p and _make_position to create the right child Position instance.
    arrayIndex = self._validate(p)
    if arrayIndex._right is not None:
      raise ValueError('Left child exists')
    self._size += 1
    arrayIndex._right = self._array(e, 2*p + 2)
    return self._make_position(arrayIndex._right)
```

Thanks//

Comment: Why do the method names start with an underscore? The habit is that a leading underscore indicates that the method that should be taken as private, but surely you want to allow a user of your implementation to add nodes...

Comment: What is the code for `_validate` or `_make_position`? Is there any boilerplate code that you are *required* to use?

Comment: You don't need a node class for an array based tree. If the parent index is `p` then the left child index is `(2*p)+1` and the right child index is `(2*p)+2`.

Comment: Well, this is not really productive... you should respond to comments. Moving on...

Comment: @trincot Sorry mate, yes there is both code for _validate and _make_position. Where _validate returns the associated array index, if position is valid. And _make_position return position instance for given array index. I can put both the boilerplated code in the question.

Comment: The boiler plate code may be interesting to include -- but only if that is a *required* part of the solution. I now also see you have a class `Position`: so you are allowed to use a `Position` class, but not a `Node` class? What is the definition of `Position`? Is that class *given*, or is that your implementation?

Comment: Yes i am allow to use a position class and not a node class, i will put the position class in the question.

Comment: My question remains: is that class *given*, or is that your implementation. Maybe I am not clear. I am really asking you to clarify which code is *given* and therefore *fixed*, and which code is your part. Should our answers stick to any code, or is this a completely open question where we may come up with *any* implementation, that can have any classes, except that they should not have the name `Node`!?

Comment: @trincot Yes, the given code is the position class, _validate and _make_position. And my part is the _add root etc where i should not change the given code, sorry im both new to stackoverflow and python so i clearly missed to clarify what should not be done and what should be done.

Comment: Can you edit your question and clearly indicate which parts of the code are given & fixed, and which parts are from your hand and are open for us to alter and extend? NB: I find your "Yes" confusing. It seems to suggest we can do anything we want, but then you say there is given code we should not change. Maybe it is because I asked my question in different ways...

Comment: @trincot Yes sure, ive change so you can see the whole code, and ive written above the code what is given and what is not, to clarify is everything given except the nonpublic mutators in the code. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: OK, I think this is clear. Now we need to know what exactly is your question. Obviously we are not going to solve this whole assignment for you. But you can pinpoint where exactly you are stuck (which lines of code, what do you get, what *should* you have got, ...), and then we could answer to that specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing looks like a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) (tree).  With zero based indexing, you can compute the index of the left child and right child of any position `p` using `leftIndex = 2*p+1` and `rightIndex = 2*p+2`.

For implementation, I would suggest a few helper methods that assign a value at a given position and extends the array as needed, get the value at a given position and get the left and right child positions:

```
def setValue(self,p,value):
     while p>=len(self._array): self._array.append(None)
     self._size    += (self._array[p] is None)-(value is None)
     self._array[p] = value

def getValue(self,p):
     if p>=len(self._array): return None
     return self._array[p]

def getLeftPos(self,p):  return p*2+1
def getRightPos(self,p): return p*2+2
```

You can use these methods to implement the other functions:

```
def setRoot(self,value): self.setValue(0,value)

def setLeft(self,p,value):
    if self.getValue(p) is None: 
        raise ValueError('Parent does not exist')
    self.setValue(self.getLeftPos(p),value)

def setRight(self,p,value):
    if self.getValue(p) is None: 
        raise ValueError('Parent does not exist')
    self.setValue(self.getRightPos(p),value)
```

*From this you can add more validations such as preventing reassignments or ensuring that the tree remains balanced, etc.*

An alternative approach that would be more memory efficient than a binary heap would be to store tuples in your array containing the value and the position of the left and right children.

The implementation would then look a bit different but the same helper methods would keep the code simple:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._maxArraySize = 512
    self._array = [(None,None,None)]*self._maxArraySize
    self._size = 0

def setValue(self,p,value): 
    _,left,right = self._array[p]
    self._size   = max(self._size,p+1)
    return self._array[p] = (value,left,right)

def getValue(self,p):    return self._array[p][0]

def getLeftPos(self,p):  return self._array[p][1]

def getRightPos(self,p): return self._array[p][2]
```

And the element adding methods would then be:

```
def setRoot(self,value):
    self.setValue(0,value)
    return 0

def setLeft(self,p,value):
    left = self.getLeftPos(p) or self._size
    self.setValue(left,value)
    self._array[p] = (self.getValue(p),left,self.getRightPos(p))
    return left

def setRight(self,p,value):
    right = self.getRightPos(p) or self._size
    self.setValue(right,value)
    self._array[p] = (self.getValue(p),self.getLeftPos(p),right)
    return right
```

*You can add more validations to these as well (max size, existing parent, etc.)*

Comment: Oh interesting, how should i implement that in the code, im kinda new in python as you can see.

Comment: I don't see the conditions in the OP's question that indicate that it is a binary heap. A binary heap must be a complete tree... That seems not to be guaranteed here. Still, the data structure could be used, if we are OK with a potentially large footprint for a very unbalanced tree.

Comment: That was indeed a bit of inference on my part based on the inputs and outputs being positions.  There may be other data structures that would support/manage a more optimal use of "positions" but binary heaps are a well known model for position based storage of a binary tree.